# Curly brackets Norwegian ( Macintosh, no dead keys ) - how to enable them?

Tags: 20.04, keyboard-layout, visual-studio-code

How to enable curly brackets in said keyboard on MacbookPro?
What i want, after a bit of thinkering, is to have the special characters wich norwegian has, Windows10 formatting for the keyboard.
W10 formatting means cmd shift 7 and 0 for curly brackets.

Maybe this helps in solving the issue...

I am truly lost and will appreciate any help.

Alexander

Answer (score 1):

With the basic *Norwegian* layout you access those symbols via <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> respecive <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>. So one option is to use that layout instead.

As regards *Norwegian (Macintosh, no dead keys)*, and unlike most other layouts, it does not automatically enable a key for accessing 3rd and 4th level keys, so you need to do that yourself. You can do that by opening *Tweaks* (the `gnome-tweaks` package needs to be installed) and then *Keyboard & Mouse -> Additional Layout Options -> Key to choose the 3rd level*.

If you pick <kbd>Right Alt</kbd>, you can do

<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> => }

But

<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> results in a bar, so it looks like you need to edit the layout as well...

Are you sure you don't prefer the basic *Norwegian* keyboard layout? :)

Comment: I am not sure about the Norwegian keyboard, could be that is all i need. I am new to Ubuntu on Macbook, is the basic Norwegian keyboard in gnome tweak_

Comment: @SinisterAlex: No, you would add it in _Settings -> Region & Language -> Input Sources_. If you do, you can easily switch between the two and compare, and decide later which one you prefer.